# Confused: would correlation be "--" in Statsample?

Tags: ruby, statistics

I am very new to statsample and having some basic questions. With this sample data:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 3],[2, 3, 3, 5],[4, 1, 3, 4]]
```

I create a 4x4 statsample dataaset called ds and get the following output for each call:

```
        puts ds.summary
```

gets

```
= Dataset 1
  Cases: 3
  Element:[actuals]
  == Vector 3
    n :3
    n valid:3
    factors:3
    mode: 3
    Distribution
+---+---+---------+
| 3 | 3 | 100.00% |
+---+---+---------+

  Element:[mids]
  == Vector 2
    n :3
    n valid:3
    factors:1,2,3
    mode: 2
    Distribution
+---+---+--------+
| 1 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 2 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 3 | 1 | 33.33% |
+---+---+--------+

  Element:[predicteds]
  == Vector 4
    n :3
    n valid:3
    factors:3,4,5
    mode: 3
    Distribution
+---+---+--------+
| 3 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 4 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 5 | 1 | 33.33% |
+---+---+--------+

  Element:[prediction_error]
  == Vector 5
    n :3
    n valid:3
    factors:0,1,2
    mode: 0
    Distribution
+---+---+--------+
| 0 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 1 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 2 | 1 | 33.33% |
+---+---+--------+

  Element:[uids]
  == Vector 1
    n :3
    n valid:3
    factors:1,2,4
    mode: 1
    Distribution
+---+---+--------+
| 1 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 2 | 1 | 33.33% |
| 4 | 1 | 33.33% |
+---+---+--------+
```

Which seems reasonable but then:

```
cm = ds.correlation_matrix
puts cm.summary
```

gets this, which is confusing:

```
Correlation Matrix
+------------------+---------+-------+------------+------------------+-------+
|                  | actuals | mids  | predicteds | prediction_error | uids  |
+------------------+---------+-------+------------+------------------+-------+
| actuals          | 1.000   | --    | --         | --               | --    |
| mids             | --      | 1.000 | --         | --               | --    |
| predicteds       | --      | --    | 1.000      | --               | --    |
| prediction_error | --      | --    | --         | 1.000            | --    |
| uids             | --      | --    | --         | --               | 1.000 |
+------------------+---------+-------+------------+------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a dataset with nominal vectors, not scalar ones. So, correlations between not numeric vectors is always 0.